# Given that we have to find the $ Curl (V)$. How could we find $\phi$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, partial-derivative, curl

**Question :** By calculating $\nabla \times V$, show that

$$V~(x, y , z )=\begin{pmatrix} ~yz^2+3\\ xz^2+2z+1\\ 2xyz+2y\end{pmatrix}$$

can be expressed as *V* $=\nabla \phi$ for some function $\phi$, and find $\phi$.

**What I have calculated/ my Answer**: $\nabla \times V = Curl(V)$

$$Curl(V) = \begin{bmatrix} \hat{i}& \hat{j} & \hat{k}\\ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \\ yz^2+3& xz^2+2z+1& 2xyz+2y\end{bmatrix}$$

$\space$

$Curl(V) = ~\hat{i} { \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial}{\partial y }& \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \\
xz^2+2z+1& 2xyz+2xy\\
\end{bmatrix}  } $$-\hat{j}  { \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x }& \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \\
yz^2+3& 2xyz+2xy\\
\end{bmatrix} } $

$+\hat{k}  { \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x }& \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \\
yz^2+3&x^2+2z+1\\
\end{bmatrix} }$

$\space $

$ Curl(V) = ~\hat{i} { \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial}{\partial y }(2xyz+2y) - \frac{\partial}{\partial z}(xz^2+2z+1)
\end{bmatrix}  }  $ $-\hat{j} { \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x }(2xyz+2y) - \frac{\partial}{\partial z}(yz^3+3)
\end{bmatrix}  }  $ $\space$

$-\hat{k} { \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x }(xz^2+2z+1) - \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(yz^3+3)
\end{bmatrix}  }  $

$\space$

$$Curl(V) = \langle ~0 ~\hat{i}- 0~\hat{j} ~ +0~\hat{k}\rangle = 0$$

**Note : we know that curl (gradient vector)** $= 0$

$$~Curl(\nabla \phi) = 0 $$

**Hence, proved :**

$$  V =\nabla \phi$$

**Finding :**

$$V =\nabla \phi$$

$$(yz^2+3)~\hat{i} ~+ (xz^2+2z+1)~\hat{j} ~+ (2xyz+2y)~\hat{k} = ~ \frac{\partial \phi } {\partial x}~\hat{i} + \frac{\partial \phi } {\partial y}~\hat{j} + \frac{\partial \phi } {\partial z}~\hat{k}  $$

Written as :

$$  \frac{\partial \phi } {\partial x} =    yz^2+3    $$

$$ \frac{\partial \phi } {\partial y} = xz^2+2z+1$$

$$  \frac{\partial \phi } {\partial z} = 2xyz+2y$$

**Un-doing the partial differentiation :**

with respect to $~ \partial{x}, ~ \phi = xyz^2 + 3x + C_1(y,z)$

with respect to $~ \partial{y}, ~\phi =  xyz^2+ 2yz + y + C_2(x,z)$

with respect to $~ \partial{z}, ~\phi =  xyz^2 + 2yz + C_3(x,y) $

**Final :** $$\phi ~(x,y,z) = xyz^2 + 2yz + 3x + y + C_1(y,z)+ C_2(x,z) + C_3(x,y) $$

Could you guys please verify my steps and my final answer

Comment: @Arthur oh, let me make the necessary changes.

Comment: @Arthur made changes, could verify the answer  please

Comment: no, the $y$  partial comes out wrong.

Comment: @WillJagy thanks for the response. I will go through it again

Comment: I would add that your constants are not actually constant: $C_1 = C_1(y,z) $ for example

Comment: @WillJagy right makes sense.

Comment: @WillJagy made the changes

Comment: In the final step, you need to remove $C$ terms otherwise it is all good.

Comment: You need to use your expression for $V$ and your knowledge of $\nabla V$ to deduce what $\nabla(C_1(y,z)+C_2(x,z)+C_3(x,y))$ is, and try to figure out what $C_1(y,z)+C_2(x,z)+C_3(x,y)$ could be.

Comment: @Arthur I did that and $C_1 (y,z) + C_2(x,z)+C_3(x,y)$ comes out to be a constants. Is that right or is there more to it ?

Comment: @Arthur they don’t have a variables , only constants.

Comment: @Gaurang If you have found that $\nabla(C_1(y,z)+C_2(x,z)+C_3(x,y)) = 0$, then yes, $C_1(y,z)+C_2(x,z)+C_3(x,y)$ is a constant. In that case, you can pick whichever constant you want. It doesn't matter. $\nabla\phi$ is the same either way.

Comment: @Arthur thanks, yes understandable